# Parsing text file to jagged array

Tags: java, jagged-arrays

I have the following file

```
3
2,3,4,5
6,7,8
9,10
```

and I am trying to convert it to pass it as jagged array of double. By that I mean, I am trying to store this as

```
double[][] myArray = {{2,3,4},{6,7},{9}}
double[] secondArray = {5,8,10}
```

I have been able to get the values read from the file but I am stuck on 2 things.

1. How can I convert the values into double array?
2. How can I store the last elements into a new array?

I am facing the error because my array contains comma separated values but how can I get the individual values to convert to double? I am still new to Java so I am not aware of all the inbuilt methods.

here is what I have so far

```
public double[] fileParser(String filename) {

    File textFile = new File(filename);
    String firstLine = null;
    String secondLine = null;
    String[] secondLineTokens = null;

    FileInputStream fstream = null;
    try {
        fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    try {
        firstLine = br.readLine(); // reads the first line
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((secondLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            myList.add(secondLine);
            //secondLineTokens = secondLine.split(",");

        }

        String[] linesArray = myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
        for(int i = 0; i<linesArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println("tokens are: " + linesArray[i]);
        }

        double[] arrDouble = new double[linesArray.length];
        for(int i=0; i<linesArray.length; i++)
        {
           arrDouble[i] = Double.parseDouble(linesArray[i]); #error here
        }



    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the first line gives you the number of lines in the rest of the file. You can leverage it to make the arrays upfront, like this:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
double a[][] = new double[n][];
double b[] = new double[n];
for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
    String[] tok = br.readLine().split(",");
    a[i] = new double[tok.length-1];
    for (int j = 0 ; j != a[i].length ; j++) {
        a[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(tok[j]);
    }
    b[i] = Double.parseDouble(tok[tok.length-1]);
}
```

Similarly, you can use `String.split` method to find out how many entries is to be added to the jagged array. This way the code becomes much shorter, because you can pre-allocate all your arrays.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/5fHB4E)